Rudin's RCA 2.24 theorem : Lusin's theorem
As precised in the title of my question, the context is the book of Walter Rudin : Real and Complex analysis. And especially the proof of theorem 2.24 (Lusin's theorem) which I put below.
I have a question concerning the affirmation : "There are compact sets $K_n$ and open sets $V_n$ such that $K_n \subset T_n \subset V_n \subset V$ and $µ(V_n-K_n)<2^{-n} \epsilon$."
How do we know this is true ? I understand that according to theorem 2.14 (Riesz representation theorem) it is true for each set $E$ provided that $E$ is measurable and its measure is finite.
So my question could be rephrased as follows : How do we know that each $T_n$ is measurable ?
Here is the theorem 2.24 from Rudin's book :



I've upvoted your question, is your reputation now high enough to import that image in your question?

The assumptions on the problem are not given here. Perhaps it is an assumption that $T_n$ is a measurable subset of some set of interest.

There's this thing called Google $\ldots$ Google search for: "Rudin" + "Lusin's theorem" + 2.24
